# Using the Bitcoin python library to generate Private Key [Noob question]

Tags: private-key, python

I have done `pip install bitcoin` and then wrote the below code:

```
from bitcoin import *
private_key = random_key()
print(private_key)
```

Now I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/praveen/Documents/code/sandbox/python/bitcoinkey.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bitcoinkey import *
  File "/Users/praveen/Documents/code/sandbox/python/bitcoinkey.py", line 2, in <module>
    private_key = random_key()
NameError: name 'random_key' is not defined
```

Any idea why 'random_key' is not defined?

Thanks,
Just getting started with tinkering.

Comment: By pip installing bitcoin you are installing an unmaintained Bitcoin library https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools. I'd recommend you use another. https://github.com/ofek/bit, https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib, https://github.com/mcdallas/cryptotools etc

Comment: Thank you ! I will test this further

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import bitcoin, base58, ecdsa, requests, smtplib, multiprocessing, blockchain
import gc
import sys
gc.collect()

while True:

    private_key = random_key()
    public_key = privtopub(private_key)
    address = pubtoaddr(public_key)

    with open("btc.txt", "r") as m:
        add = m.read().split()
        for ad in add:
                continue
        if address in add:
            print("Found"+ " " +address+ ' ' +private_key)
            data = open("data.txt","a")
            data.write(print(address+ ' ' +private_key+ ' ' +"\n")) 
            data.close()

        else:
            print(address+ ' ' +private_key)
del (address)
del (private_key)
os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + [sys.argv[0]])
```